# who is faster between without union query and a union query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

I have already created a big select query by oracle  where i need to insert 13 type of different select query with **UNION**. I want to know that,if i capable to reduce the **UNION** and create them by join query then what will be the best for me, with UNION query or without UNION query?

Who gives me the data very fast, with **UNION** or without **UNION** ?

Lets give you an example to clear my question:

> 1. It's a **Without UNION** query

```
SELECT customer_name, SUM (CURRENT_TOTAL) CURRENT_TOTAL
    FROM (SELECT CASE
                    WHEN gc.id = 11 THEN 'GOVT (Defence)'
                    WHEN gc.id <> 11 THEN 'GOVT (Except Defence)'
                 END
                    customer_name,
                 CB.CURRENT_TOTAL
            FROM cust_domestic c
                 JOIN GOVERNMENT_CUSTOMERS gc ON c.code = gc.cust_code
                 JOIN customer_bill cb ON cb.cust_code = c.code)
    GROUP BY customer_name
```

> 2. It's a **With UNION** query

```
SELECT 'GOVT (Defence)' customer_name, SUM (CB.CURRENT_TOTAL) CURRENT_TOTAL
  FROM cust_domestic c
       JOIN GOVERNMENT_CUSTOMERS gc ON c.code = gc.cust_code
       JOIN customer_bill cb ON cb.cust_code = c.code
 WHERE gc.id = 11
UNION
SELECT 'GOVT (Defence)' customer_name, SUM (CB.CURRENT_TOTAL) CURRENT_TOTAL
  FROM cust_domestic c
       JOIN GOVERNMENT_CUSTOMERS gc ON c.code = gc.cust_code
       JOIN customer_bill cb ON cb.cust_code = c.code
 WHERE gc.id <> 11
```

> *Both of them give me the following result*

```
Customer_name            |    CURRENT_TOTAL
------------------------------------------- 
GOVT (Defence)           |           29020
GOVT (Except Defence)    |      2121974363
```

Now my question is who is give me better performance , consider the time and give me the result faster ?

Who is better query between them?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the first conditional aggregation approach you used should outperform the union approach, as the former only requires a single scan of the tables.  But, I would rewrite it without using a subquery:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN gc.id = 11 THEN CB.CURRENT_TOTAL ELSE 0 END) AS "GOVT (Defence)",
    SUM(CASE WHEN gc.id <> 11 THEN CB.CURRENT_TOTAL ELSE 0 END) AS "GOVT (Except Defence)"
FROM cust_domestic c
INNER JOIN GOVERNMENT_CUSTOMERS gc
    ON c.code = gc.cust_code
INNER JOIN customer_bill cb
    ON cb.cust_code = c.code;
```

But, as a side note, this approach actually gives the output as a single record with two columns for the two sums, rather than two records.

Comment: Actually, I need two record not two column.

Comment: Then your first approach might also still be optimal, because it only requires a single join/scan to generate the sums and labels.  The union approach does not scale well, because you need a separate query for each label.